# How do you capture the text on the first page of a Microsoft Word document?

Tags: vb.net, interop, ms-word, vsto

Using VB.NET how do you capture the text on the first page of a Microsoft Word document?  I've imported the Word 12 interop library (for Word 2007), and I know how to use the document.range function, but how do you know which page you're on when you're selecting text?

Answer (score 2):

Roughly speaking, you don't. Word doesn't have a solid concept of pages... See http://daiya.mvps.org/wordpages.htm for example.

You could try something like:

```
docMyDocument.Bookmarks("\Page").Range
```

Which *mostly* works, but isn't guaranteed to. (It fails if there are tables stradding the end of the page, for example...)

see also http://support.microsoft.com/kb/212555